# Pivot For Dynamic Column Value

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

May Some One Please help me how to get the below output.
**SQL SERVER 2008**

```
CREATE TABLE #TABLE
(
[Generic Name] varchar(15),
[Description]varchar(15)
)

INSERT #TABLE

SELECT 'RESISTOR',  'POWER' UNION ALL
SELECT 'RESISTOR',  'Type' UNION ALL
SELECT 'RESISTOR',  'DESIGN' UNION ALL
SELECT 'RESISTOR',  'Material'
```

**result for each Generic Name , Design, Material,other, Power and TYPE as Value of the column under Column Name as Desc1, Desc2....DescN**

```
**Generic Name    DESC1   ,DESC2  ,DESC2, DESC4   
RESISTOR        POWER   , Type    DESIGN, Material**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to do it dynamicly:

```
CREATE TABLE T1
(
[Generic Name] varchar(15),
[Description]varchar(15)
)

INSERT T1

SELECT 'RESISTOR',  'POWER' UNION ALL
SELECT 'RESISTOR',  'Type' UNION ALL
SELECT 'RESISTOR',  'DESIGN' UNION ALL
SELECT 'RESISTOR',  'Material';



DECLARE @Cols NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @Sel NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @Cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(T1.Description) 
            FROM T1
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'');
SET @Sel = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(T1.Description) + ' AS DESC'+CAST(row_number () over (order by (Description)) as varchar(10))
            FROM T1
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,''); 



SET @SQL = N'
SELECT [Generic Name], '+ @Sel+ N'
FROM T1
    pivot
    (
           MAX(Description) For Description IN ('+ @Cols + N')
        ) P';

EXECUTE( @SQL);
```

Results:

```
+--------------+--------+----------+-------+-------+
| Generic Name | DESC1  |  DESC2   | DESC3 | DESC4 |
+--------------+--------+----------+-------+-------+
| RESISTOR     | DESIGN | Material | POWER | Type  |
+--------------+--------+----------+-------+-------+
```

**[Demo](http://rextester.com/CUEC91529)**

Answer (score 0):

Try the following Answer, Hope it helps you:

```
CREATE TABLE #TABLE
(
[Generic Name] varchar(15),
[Description]varchar(15)
)

INSERT INTO #TABLE

SELECT 'RESISTOR',  'POWER' UNION ALL
SELECT 'RESISTOR',  'Type' UNION ALL
SELECT 'RESISTOR',  'DESIGN' UNION ALL
SELECT 'RESISTOR',  'Material'

SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN RN=1 THEN [Generic Name] END)[Generic Name]
    ,MAX(CASE WHEN RN=1 THEN [Description] END)DESC1
    ,MAX(CASE WHEN RN=2 THEN [Description] END)DESC2
    ,MAX(CASE WHEN RN=3 THEN [Description] END)DESC3
    ,MAX(CASE WHEN RN=4 THEN [Description] END)DESC4
FROM(
    SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))RN from #TABLE
    )D

DROP TABLE #TABLE
```

Result:

```
Generic Name    DESC1   DESC2   DESC3   DESC4
RESISTOR        POWER   Type    DESIGN  Material
```

Comment: The below solution work well  for know number of values like design, material...etc, i have 5000 such values
any way to dynamically create it.